# How does a computer know other computer's IP address on a local network?

Tags: networking, ethernet

I'm currently learning about ARP and L2/L3 networking - would someone be able to help out? If I use an ethernet cable to connect my laptop (A) to another laptop (B), it could use ARP to find out B's MAC address based on B's IP address. Then, any ethernet frames could be sent and accepted by B.

But how does A know B's IP address in the first place? What if there is a switch (L2 device) in between A and B? Does this change the answer? What if there was a router in between (an L3 device)?

Comment: It sends requests to a broadcast address and gets responses back.  Many different protocols use this basic idea.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, a switch/Router will assign an IP.

The question is unclear -

> find out B's MAC address based on B's IP address.

B's MAC address is not based on B's IP.
A MAC is associated to the hardware (but somewhat assignable/cloneable) where as an IP is assigned. Either by DHCP or statically by an admin.

Effectively, you need a switch/router to make what you're defining work.

EDIT:
you can connect two computers direct, but you still need to give each a static IP address so they can find each other - this would likely  not be ona  network so the IP sub-network doesn't matter.

It still has very little to do with MAC.
If two PC's hand-shake, they'll see each others MAC.

Answer (score 0):

It sends out a broadcast packet to the broadcast MAC address asking "who has the IP address x.x.x.x" which goes to all computers on that broadcast domain.  If a computer sees that packet that owns the IP address "x.x.x.x" it will send a unicast reply back to the MAC address of the original requestor with its MAC address which will then be cached for further communication.

It doesn't know the IP unless you tell it.  You say "the default gateway is 192.168.1.1" and it will start trying to talk to 192.168.1.1 etc.

If there is a router in between, all traffic to the remote device would go to the MAC of the router and your computer wouldn't be doing any ARP lookups other than that router.

Switches wouldn't matter for this, all they do is make the broadcast domain bigger.  With a cable the broadcast domain is just you and the remote device.  With a switch, it expands that to all devices connected to the same switch (or VLAN in the switch)

Answer (score 0):

> But how does A know B's IP address in the first place?

It doesn't know. At least there's no general method to find out.

The IP address of any resource needs to be supplied by "something else". You need to either provide the address yourself, resolve it from a (also provided) DNS name, read it from a file, ... Alternatively, you need to provide some kind of auto discovery between the nodes (broadcast, multicast, LLDP, ...) or provide a commonly known discovery service, registration server or similar.

> What if there is a switch (L2 device) in between A and B?

That changes nothing but excludes link-level discovery (unless it's a "dumb" switch that simply forwards those frames).

> What if there was a router in between (an L3 device)?

That eliminates broadcast and multicast from the picture. (Multicast could be routed but that is unlikely for discovery and I won't dive into that.)

Comment: "a switch...excludes link-level discovery". Is this because LLDP uses a multicast address as the destination MAC address and the switch doesn't forward this to all ports?

Comment: A switch is supposed to not forward this kind of multicast frames, but dumb ones often do so anyway.